# How I Export some managed meta data column of sharepoint Document Library using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, powershell, taxonomyfieldvalue

I am getting the value for my text field as i need but for my taxonamy column it also give guid id and my taxonomy column are multivalued so i want to export like as store in sharepoint document library

Document Type and Document Library contain more that one value deu to multivalued field. 
First I am writing in .txt file then paste to excel sheet the value are coming like.[image]

Here is my code

```
 Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
 $site = Get-SPSite http://invi28apps9c
  $web = Get-SPWeb http://invi28apps9c/DemoTeamSite
  $list = $web.Lists["KBDocument"]
  $dList = [Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPDocumentLibrary]$list
  $items = $dList.Items
  write ("ProductNames`t" + "Version Names`t" +  "ResourceTypes`t" + "Language")
  foreach($item in $items)
 {

 write($item["ProductName"]+"`t"+$item["VersionName"]+"`t"+$item["Document Type"]+"`t"+$item["Document Language"])
  }
```